# How to stop IntelliJ IDEA debugger going through Spring Boot source code?

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

When I try to debug a Spring Boot microservice application, the IntelliJ IDEA always goes into the spring boot source code. Even though I tried to step out, the debugger iteratively goes through the spring-boot source code, and at the end of looping through the spring boot source code, the application stops executing. How can I stop this behavior?

Comment: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping | Java | Do not step into the classes.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Will doing this stop stepping into classes I have written?

Comment: @CrazyCoder This "Do not step into the classes" option is already selected in IDEA settings.

Comment: Right, but you need to add the packages you don't want to step into to the list.